# Include content outside the app in rails 3.2 views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

1. I would like to include static content as part of my normal rails views e.g. marketing content which can be text or images or both.
2. I would want marketing content to be separate from my rails code so that it can be separately updated.
3. I do not want to use content management systems.
4. Oh and I cannot not use DB, its an api driven app.

Is there a proper rails way of achieving this?

**Update**:
sorry for not being clear. I can probably explain it better with an example: I need to place some images/text on my login screen that are not part of my apps source code. That live some where on the server that can be updated async without going through my apps revision control system so they cannot be in the public folder of my app

Answer (score 0):

You can put your static marketing content in the public folder of your rails app. Your question is a little unclear and so I'm assuming you are creating a rails app to do api stuff and then have static marketing content/website.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I can probably explain it better with an example: I need to place some images/text on my login screen that are not part of my apps source code. That live some where on the server that can be updated async without going through my apps revision control system so they cannot be in the public folder of my app.